# xamarin form : how to disable tab button

Tags: xamarin.forms

i have tabbed page in which i have 3 tabs i need to enabled=false 2nd and 3rd tabs. I need to work like form wizard when i finish 1st page then 2nd tab should be enabled=true, i have tried like this as my code below, but its not working

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            x:Name="maintab"
            x:Class="OnlineKIHStore.Views.CheckOuts" 
            BarBackgroundColor="#2F3C51" 
            Title="Checkout"
            BarTextColor="White">

        <ContentPage x:Name="first" Title="Login/Register" Icon="user"  IsEnabled="True">
            <StackLayout>
        </ContentPage>
        <ContentPage x:Name="second" Title="SHIPPING" Icon="shipping" IsEnabled="False">

        </ContentPage>
        <ContentPage x:Name="third" Title="Payment" Icon="payment" IsEnabled="False">

        </ContentPage>
</TabbedPage>
```

Answer (score 0):

- If you mention "enabled=false" -You can click the tabbar. It will load the page, but will not allow to do any action in that particular page.
- If you mention "IsVisible="False"" - Still you can click the tabbar.  You can just see a empty screen.

One Method - At first don't load the tabbar you wanted. After finishing the page 1,  inserted the tabbar you needed.

Here is my sample as per your code

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        x:Name="maintab"
        x:Class="OnlineKIHStore.Views.CheckOuts" 
        BarBackgroundColor="#2F3C51" 
        Title="Checkout"
        BarTextColor="White">
<TabbedPage.Children>
    <firstPage Title="Login/Register" Icon="user"/>
    <thirdPage Title="Payment" Icon="payment"/>
</TabbedPage.Children>
```

In .CS file

```
public CheckOuts 
{ 
  InitializeComponent();
if(check_finished_pageone)
 {
    Children.Insert(2, new SecondPage { Title = "SHIPPING", Icon = "shipping" });
}}
```

Once you are done with the page1 reload the tabpage. So now your second page with new tab bar will be added.

One more method is once the page 2 is clicked you can navigate to page 1 prompting the user to finish the page 1

```
e<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        x:Name="maintab"
        x:Class="OnlineKIHStore.Views.CheckOuts" 
        BarBackgroundColor="#2F3C51" 
        Title="Checkout"
        CurrentPageChanged="TabbedPage_CurrentPageChanged"
        BarTextColor="White">
```

.CS file

```
private async void TabbedPage_CurrentPageChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
 var i = this.Children.IndexOf(this.CurrentPage);
 if (i == 2)
{
     await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error", "You have to finish the page one before navigating this page", "Ok"))
     this.CurrentPage = this.Children[0];
 }}
```

This method allows you click the 2nd tabbar, but it will re-direct to page 1 again.